# Apt-get Update stuck at 0% [archive.ubuntu.com] Ubuntu version 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04

I updated my Ubuntu version to version 18.04 from 17.10 this morning, it removed my php-fpm 7.1 and I tried to reinstall it again but I'm stuck at
the first line

```
sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152)]^C
```

I have tried a couple of fixes like

1. Editing the `gra.conf`
2. disabling IPv6 in the sysctl folder

Didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Turned our to be my ISP that has been messing around with me, I was able to resolve this by switching my ISP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could try the commands below:**

1. `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean`
2. `sudo apt-get update`

The above commands would clear the repository cache and update the system. These commands would fix your problem if it's with the software.

If the problem still persists, chances are that you have a poor network connection. Troubleshoot your network devices like routers and switches or other network equipment.

Answer (score 0):

see if the lock is on
ls /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
if so, remove it. It solved my problem. 
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

Comment: it would be really REALLY dangerous, this lock exist to prevent conflict on system files operation, and you remove it